# Typescript defining types on a object that can produce a result

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

If i have an object as such

```
let obj = {
   property1:()=>{ return Date()} // eg it doesn't have to be a date
   property2:()=>{ return 1}   
}
```

Now i want to transform this to type

```
{
   property1:Date,
   property2:number
}
```

How would i go about defining this in typescript.
Just about everything i end up doing just does get it right.

I know the properties so i know it's something like

```
type Transform<T> = Record<keyof T,?>
```

how do i get each individual property to be transformed so that the final object can be typed as well.

//Some may need a little bit more solid example

Lets say this is a react app.

```
let dependencies = {user:UserContext}:{[key:string]:React.Context<any>}
```

Now i can transform all of my react context to the actual instances inside the context using something like

```
Object.entries(contextObject).map(([key,context])=>{
   return {[key]:useContext(context)}
}).reduce((a,b)=>{
  return {...a,...b}
},{})
```

This object will be all of the properties transformed.

I take in a config object of sorts and transform the properties keeping everything the same,

This can be anything, converting some parameters to db tables,
converting dependencies to add to a class, without actually having to create the instance

Doing it isn't hard, it's having it typed so that on the other end of the transformation, i know what the type of object has been transformed into.

Comment: not sure what you exactly want here, property1 is typed Date Object, but it is defined as a function returning Date.

Comment: obj is a config object, it doesn't have to return a Date it can return anything, i think there is a solution with `[P in keyof T]` or something i just don't know or understand how to use it.

Comment: If it can return anything, how can you type it?

Comment: what about `P in keyof T` can that help in any way, it doesn't return anything, it returns what the property function returns, but each property is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in `Record` and `ReturnType` types:

```
/**
 * Apply the constraint of having functions as values.
 */
type Source = Record<string, () => any>;

/**
 * Map functions to their return types.
 */
type Transform<T extends Source> = {
    [Property in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[Property]>
}

/**
 * Make sure the argument fulfills the requirement.
 */
declare function transform<T extends Source>(source: T): Transform<T>;
```

Usage:

```
let source = {
   property1: () => { return new Date() },
   property2: () => { return 1 }   
}

/**
 * `property1` is an instance of `Date`, property2 is a `number`.
 */
const { property1, property2 } = transform(source);
```

The `transform` function can be implemented this way:

```
function transform<T extends Source>(source: T): Transform<T> {
    return Object
        .entries(source)
        .reduce(
          (cumulus, [key, value]) => Object.assign(cumulus, { [key]: value() }),
          Object.create({}),
        );
}
```

Comment: thank you this solves my current problem. Is there any way to get access to the type without it being a return type, Let's say using Context. I can likely use this as a start to figure that out but if you know the answer already as i have struggled with it for a bit and didn't know of ReturnType

Comment: Could you describe exactly what the transformation should look like? Perhaps with concrete data examples, just like you did before. I'm not familiar with Context, so I have some trouble understanding your use case.

Comment: This answer is sufficient, I'll create another post and send you a message. This has been a huge help tho.

Comment: I believe it's something to do with the infer keyword